# VS code is adding unwated word 'cons' word and semi colon on every space

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, protractor, tslint

I added some new rules in tslint but after then i started getting these error where vs code is adding 'cons' word and semicolon on space and also replaces wa in await with cons or turn in return with cons.
I am not sure why this is happening.
I tried changing the settings from user settings in user setting also added   "no-trailing-whitespace": false, and  "semicolon": [false, "always"] rules in tslint but it is not helping.I have also added a screenshot of the code. Any help would be much appreciated[image]

Below is my tslint file

```
{
  "extends": [
    "tslint-no-circular-imports",
    "tslint-eslint-rules",
    "tslint-config-prettier",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier",
    "tslint:latest"
  ],

  "rules": {
    "no-console": [true, "error"],
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "quotemark": [false, "avoid-escape"],
    "semicolon": [false, "always"],
    "indent": [true, "spaces", 4],
    "no-var-keyword": true,
    "no-default-export": true,
    "trailing-comma": [false],
    "object-literal-key-quotes": false,
    "arrow-parens": false,
    "space-before-function-paren": false,
    "no-unused-variable": true,
    "no-return-await": true,
    "no-duplicate-imports": true,
    "match-default-export-name": true,
    "max-line-length": false,
    "no-implicit-dependencies": false,
    "no-submodule-imports": false,
    "no-var-requires": false,
    "member-ordering": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "only-arrow-functions": false,
    "no-trailing-whitespace": false,
    "triple-equals": false
  },
  "rulesDirectory": ["node_modules/tslint-eslint-rules/dist/rules"]
}
```

Comment: Do you have any custom snippets or any snippets addon?

Comment: @tHeSiD No, i dont